# Difference between click() and dispatchEvent click event

Tags: javascript, html

By accident I noticed a html button on a webpage which I could click programmatically as follows

```
button.click();
```

But when I did

```
const rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect();

const options = {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    screenX: rect.x,
    screenY: rect.y,
};
const e = new Event('click', options)
btn.dispatchEvent(e);
```

it didn't work. Apparently there is a difference between the two. Can someone explain what that might be?

Comment: This is not a valid javascript

Comment: i think you want `const e = new Event('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, screenX: rect.x, screenY: rect.y })`

Comment: You're probably using jquery. That would be the difference. `$('#some_element').click()` is jquery

Comment: native js also have `click` method.

Comment: thnx, that was indeed incorrect, if fixed the typo

Comment: Can you add code snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: No, its not jquery, its in Chrome DevTools ($ and $$)

Comment: Did you search? Been asked a few times.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce a difference](https://jsbin.com/gahuwosibu/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Please [edit] to include a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, I'll update my post to with an example!

Comment: I've added the steps to reproduce

Comment: Questions are supposed to be self-contained and shouldn't rely on external links in order to be understood. If the content of that URL changes or is inaccessible for any reason for future visitors, then this question becomes useless for them

Comment: I cannot agree more, but I thought that the question: what is the difference between `click()` and `dispatchEvent(..'click'..)` would be enough. When the issue is solved I improve the reproduction steps and  remove the external url example

Comment: click() method simulates a real click event, whereas dispatchEvent triggers a synthetic event.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri what do you want to achieve/purpose ?

Comment: I want to achieve understanding and learn. As both do the same thing you might think that they are identical, which they are not. But I think I figured it out, `dispatchEvent` does work if you change `Event` with `MouseEvent`, which I guess makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Event can't be used to click a submit button**

```
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));        // <-- this fails
button.dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent('click')); // <-- this works
```

A key piece of information is that the button on the page is a form submit button. This why the page reloads as noted in the question.

```
<button type="submit">Zoek</button>
```

Both the click method and dispatchEvent will cause a click event. No problems with this part.

The actual problem is that OP is using a generic base [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) to click a form submit button.  This doesn't work because the generic event won't cause a submit event to be fired after the click.

Yet, if we instead use [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) the form is submitted and the page reloads:

**Test Snippet**

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let button = document.querySelector('button[type=submit]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // do not reload page
  console.log(`${e.target.tagName} event: ${e.type}`);
})

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevents form submit on click
  console.log(`${e.target.tagName}, event: ${e.type}`);

})

console.log('Using click method');
button.click();

console.log('Using Event - no following submit');
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));

console.log('Using PointerEvent');
button.dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));

console.log('end test');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit">Zoek</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following experiment shows up one difference between the methods (there may be others):

- Clicking the button itself produces an event with `pointerType: "mouse"`.
- The `click()` method produces an event with `pointerType: ""`.
- Dispatching an Event (or even a MouseEvent) gives `pointerType: undefined`.
- Dispatching a PointerEvent gives `pointerType: ""`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.pointerType);
});
```

```html
<button>Event Target</button>
<span onclick="btn.click()">Click</span>
<span onclick="btn.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))">Dispatch</span>
<span onclick="btn.dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent('click'))">DispatchPointer</span>
<span onclick="btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))">DispatchMouse</span>
```

Comment: I get `undefined` logged for any of these. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr5zX.gif

Comment: Browser dependencies?

Comment: For me it is working like Heiko described (Google Chrome Version 117.0.5938.150, Windows 10)

Answer (score -1):

Both work for me

Notice that both of them have to be triggered by a user interation

```js
function clickOtherButton() {
  const rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect();

  const options = {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    screenX: rect.x,
    screenY: rect.y,
  };
  const e = new Event('click', options)
  btn.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="alert(1)">btn</button>
<button onclick="clickOtherButton()">click me</button>
```

```js
function clickOtherButton() {
  btn.click()
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="alert(1)">btn</button>
<button onclick="clickOtherButton()">click me</button>
```

Comment: It works for me even without user interaction.